# Cannot find my project's R.class

Tags: android

I have no errors in my res/ dir, yet, all my java files cannot find the compiled version of my R.java because it is failing to compile.

What am I overlooking??[image]

Comment: Are you using the same package name in your manifest and source code?

Comment: Do you have a gen folder in your project? Are you using Eclipse? Did you create the project as Android project? Do you have errors in the source code?

Comment: nothing is in my gen folder. Why?

Comment: You must have a list of errors in the `Problems` view (Window -> Show View -> Problems). One or more of those will be unrelated to both `R` and the build path. If there are none, clean the project and all libraries and retry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error basically someone at Google didn't figure out that the R library will get mixed up with other stuff.

Comment: Do you have errors in the source code, or in the build path? That could be the reason compilation files and because of that the files are not generated.

Comment: I supressed the translation issues from Android-Lint

Comment: Uhm, you don't have a build target. I think you should have at least one, otherwise, what are you building...?

Comment: Yeah, I have not touched this project in many months. something must be wrong.

Comment: Based on the image you uploaded, you do not have the android sdk installed or you have not set its location in Window->Preferences->Android->SDK location.  The Android Project Build Target pane should show the available platforms, it shouldn't be empty

Comment: Yeah, I had v18 of the sdk...it needs 20.. someone want to submit answer for easy points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do not import any `R` files. Check your import statements to make sure you aren't including `android.R` or `com.google.maps.R` or `whatever.whatever.whatever.R`.
- Check if you have any errors, especially with your layout files. Sometimes, Eclipse's error-checker will miss some XML errors and these will trip up your auto-generation.
- Make sure you have the proper build path selected. Right-click your project in the Package Explorer, go to `Properties -> Android -> Project Build Target`. Check your desired build target.
- Make sure everything is up-to-date (Eclipse, the Android SDK, tools, etc.)
- If all else fails, just restart your Eclipse. If that doesn't work, restart your computer. You'd surprised how often a simple restart will fix your problems.